# how to swap two Integer wrapper objects

Tags: java, reference, integer

How can I swap the contents of two Integer wrappers?

```
void swap(Integer a,Integer b){
   /*We can't use this as it will not reflect in calling program,and i know why
    Integer c = a;
    a= b;
    b = c;
   */
  //how can i swap them ? Does Integer has some setValue kind of method?
  //if yes
    int c = a;
    a.setValue(b);
    b.setValue(c);

}
```

Comment: Too bad Stackoverflow does not check spelling in posts. Oh wait, it does! Quite a feat that you still managed to post something almost illegible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, precisely because `Integer` is immutable (along with the other primitive wrapper types). If you had a mutable wrapper class, it would be fine:

```
public final class MutableInteger {
{
    private int value;

    public MutableInteger(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

void swap(MutableInteger a, MutableInteger b) {
    int c = a.getValue();
    a.setValue(b.getValue());
    b.setValue(c); 
}
```

However, due to the lack of the equivalent of `setValue` in `Integer`, there's basically no way of doing what you're asking. **That's a good thing.** It means that for *most* cases, where we may want to pass an `Integer` value to another method, we don't need to worry about whether the method will mutate it. Immutability makes it much easier to *reason* about your code, without having to carefully trace what every method does, just in case it changes your data under your feet.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapper types in Java are immutable hence provide no setter methods. Plus Java works by passing references by value. Can you tell us why you want to swap stuff?

Comment: Because people ask this question in interviews :-)

Answer (score 1):

The type `java.lang.Integer` represents an *immutable* number that will never change its value. If you want a *mutable* number, try `MutableInt` from Apache Commons.

In Java, as opposed to C++, you cannot pass references to arbitrary memory locations, so swapping is impossible in most cases. The closest thing you can get is this:

```
public static void swap(Integer[] ints, int index1, int index2) {
  Integer tmp = ints[index1];
  ints[index1] = ints[index2];
  ints[index2] = tmp;
}
```

You can write similar code using a `List<T>`, but you always need a container (or two) in which you can swap things.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this article to get a clear idea [Article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html)

You will get a clear idea about pass by value pass by reference and and its concepts

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this :

```
class MyClass{
int a = 10 , b = 20;
public void swap(MyClass obj){
    int c;
    c = obj.a;
    obj.a = obj.b;
    obj.b = c;
}
public static void main(String a[]){
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    System.out.println("a : "+obj.a);
    System.out.println("b : "+obj.b);
    obj.swap(obj);
    System.out.println("new a : "+obj.a);
    System.out.println("new b : "+obj.b);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NewInteger {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public NewInteger(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void swap(){
        int c = this.a;
        this.a = this.b;
        this.b = c;
    }
}


NewInteger obj = new NewInteger(1, 2);
System.out.println(obj.getA());
System.out.println(obj.getB());
obj.swap();
System.out.println(obj.getA());
System.out.println(obj.getB());
```

output :
1
2
2
1